# Using regex with newline "\n"

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it possible to use regex in spite of the newline character `\n`

e.g. this code works well

```
> "|text|".gsub(/\|(.+?)\|/){"###"}
=> "###"
```

this doesn't

```
> "|\n text|".gsub(/\|(.+?)\|/){"###"}
=> "|\n text|"
```

Comment: Not a bad, question. I don't understand the downvote. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the m modifier for multiline matches:

```
"|\n text|".gsub(/\|(.+?)\|/m){"###"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the m modifier (specific to your case):

```
"|\n text|".gsub(/\|([^\|]+?)\|/){"###"}
```

It will match until the next `|`.